# php recursion, function doesn't return any value

Tags: php, recursion, return

I want my function to return whole url, starting from node with given id, and serching for parents, last one has parent_id =1.
My function almost works, in echo"$wholeUrl "; i have my url, but function doesn't retun it and I don't know wtf, please help.

Here's my *code*:

```php
function getUrl($xml,$id){
    $wholeUrl="";
    $wholeUrl= getMyUrl($xml,$id,$wholeUrl);
    return $wholeUrl;
}

function getMyUrl($xml,$idWew, $wholeUrl) {
    foreach ($xml as $node) {
        $par = $node->parent_id;
        $ide = $node->id;
        $url = $node->url;
        $name = $node->name;
        settype($par,'integer');
        settype($ide,'integer');

        if($ide==$idWew){
            $wholeUrl=$url."/".$wholeUrl;
            if($par==1){
                echo"$wholeUrl ";
                return $wholeUrl;
                break;
            } else {
                getMyUrl($xml,$par,$wholeUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r(getUrl($xmlcat,1877));
```

`$xmlcat` is flat array with this structure:

```text
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => 1876
    [parent_id] => 1
    [name] => blablabla, bla, bla
    [url] => bla-bla-bla-bla
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return getMyUrl:

```
    /* .... */
    }else{

        return getMyUrl($xml,$par,$wholeUrl);
    }
    /* .... */
```

Answer (score 1):

You must `return getMyUrl($xml,$par,$wholeUrl);` as well.
Otherwise the outer `getMyUrl` continues in the `foreach` loop and searches the next node.