# Merge two variable SimpleXML Objects in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've been trying to merge two XML files I use to build my menubar in my web application for hours, but I can't get it to work. 
I have my main XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<root>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <menu>
        <Category1>
            <item>
                <id>Cake</id>
                <nr>1</nr>
                <hint>I like these</hint>
                <userlevel>5</userlevel>                
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Cake 2</id>
                <nr>2</nr>
                <hint>I like these too, but only for me</hint>
                <userlevel>10</userlevel>               
            </item>
        <Category1>

        <Category2WithApples>
        <item>
            <id>Apple Cake</id>
            <nr>1</nr>
            <hint>Sweet</hint>
            <userlevel>5</userlevel>                
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>Rainbow Cake</id>
            <nr>2</nr>
            <hint>Mine!!</hint>
            <userlevel>10</userlevel>               
        </item>
        <Category2WithApples>
    </menu>
</root>
```

Now, I want each user to be able to load in his custom XML which is in the same folder as the main.xml which looks like this:

```
<CategoryMyOwn>
    <item>
        <id>Item in my Category</id>
        <nr>0</nr>
        <hint>Some text</hint>
        <userlevel>0</userlevel>                
    </item>
</CategoryMyOwn>
<Category1>
    <item>
        <id>Item in existing category</id>
        <nr>0</nr>
        <hint>Some text</hint>
        <userlevel>0</userlevel>                
    </item>
</Category1>
```

I've tried solutions from

- http://php.net/manual/de/ref.simplexml.php
- [php recursion, function doesn't return any value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788690/php-recursion-function-doesnt-return-any-value)
- http://durgagupta.com.np/php-how-to-merge-two-simplexml-objects/

but they all do not work at all for me or just append the second file to the end of my main.xml. So, my question is, how do I properly merge the user.xml into my main.xml so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<root>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <menu>
        <Category1>
            <item>
                <id>Cake</id>
                <nr>1</nr>
                <hint>I like these</hint>
                <userlevel>5</userlevel>                
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Cake 2</id>
                <nr>2</nr>
                <hint>I like these too, but only for me</hint>
                <userlevel>10</userlevel>               
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Item in existing category</id>
                <nr>0</nr>
                <hint>Some text</hint>
                <userlevel>0</userlevel>                
            </item>
        <Category1>

        <Category2WithApples>
        <item>
            <id>Apple Cake</id>
            <nr>1</nr>
            <hint>Sweet</hint>
            <userlevel>5</userlevel>                
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>Rainbow Cake</id>
            <nr>2</nr>
            <hint>Mine!!</hint>
            <userlevel>10</userlevel>               
        </item>
        <Category2WithApples>

        <CategoryMyOwn>
            <item>
                <id>Item in my Category</id>
                <nr>0</nr>
                <hint>Some text</hint>
                <userlevel>0</userlevel>                
            </item>
        </CategoryMyOwn>

    </menu>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second XML is not a document, XML documents need to have a document element node. In other words here at the top level only a single element node is allowed. All other element nodes have to be descendants of that node.

You can treat this as an XML fragment however. A fragment is the inner XML of an element node.

In both cases it easier to use DOM for that.

### Append a fragment to a parent element node

Let's keep it simple for the first step and append the fragment to the `menu` node.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($targetXml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml($fragmentXml);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/root/menu[1]') as $menu) {
  $menu->appendChild($fragment);
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

The Xpath expression can `/root/menu[1]` selects the first `menu` element node inside the `root`. This can be only one node or none.

A document fragment in DOM is a node object and can be appended like any other node (element, text, ...).

### Merging nodes

Merging the category nodes is a little more difficult. But Xpath will help.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($targetXml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml($fragmentXml);

$menu = $xpath->evaluate("/root/menu[1]")->item(0);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('*', $fragment) as $category) {
  $targets = $xpath->evaluate("{$category->nodeName}[1]", $menu);
  if ($targets->length > 0) {
    $targetCategory = $targets->item(0);
    foreach ($category->childNodes as $item) {
      $targetCategory->appendChild($item);
    }
  } else {
    $menu->appendChild($category);
  }
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```

#### Fetching the menu node

```
$menu = $xpath->evaluate("/root/menu[1]")->item(0);
```

This is about the same like in the first simple example. It fetch the `menu` nodes in `root` and returns the first found node. You should check if the list contained a node. But for this example just take it for guaranteed.

#### Iterating the fragment

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('*', $fragment) as $category) {
  ...
}
```

`*` is a simple Xpath expression that returns any element child node. The fragment can contain other nodes (whitespace, text, comment, ...). The second argument for DOMXpath::evaluate() is the context for the Xpath expression.

#### Fetching the target category

Next you need to fetch the category node with the same name from the target document. This will return a list with one node or an empty list.

```
$targets = $xpath->evaluate("{$category->nodeName}[1]", $menu);
if ($targets->length > 0) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

#### Append to the found target category

If the category exists append all child nodes from the category in the fragment to the target.

```
$targetCategory = $targets->item(0);
foreach ($category->childNodes as $item) {
  $targetCategory->appendChild($item);
}
```

#### Append a category

```
$menu->appendChild($category);
```

If the category doesn't exists, just append it to the `menu`.

Comment: Would it be easier to change the second XML to have the same "format" as the first one? Like adding the root and menu nodes.

Comment: No, just a different. You could still use Xpath to fetch nodes from the second XML document. But if you load it into a second document object, you would have to use DOMDocument::importNode() to import the nodes into the target document. Basically you would have two Xpath objects (one for each document), the Xpath for the source would change a little (because you change the structure) and you would have to use something like `$targetCategory->appendChild($document->importNode($item, true));` DOM methods are designed to do only a single little task and to be combined.

Comment: can you mention what's the `$targetXml` and `$fragmentXml`?